# Update user profile "Manager" property throws PropertyNotEditableException in Sharepoint Online…

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

When i tried to update "Manager" field in Sharepoint online with API Rest, throws an exception. I am a global admin of the tenant.

> "{"odata.error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyNotEditableException","message":{"lang":"es-ES","value":"Propiedad
>   no editable: esta propiedad solo puede modificarla un
>   administrador."}}}

This is the code:

```
 function updateManager() {
     var selectedUser = $("#usuarios").find(":selected")[0].value;
  var newManager = $("#newManagers").find(":selected")[0].value;



    var requestHeaders = {
        'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    };

    var userData = {
        'accountName': "i:0#.f|membership|" + selectedUser ,
        'propertyName': 'Manager', //can also be used to set custom single value profile properties
        'propertyValue': "i:0#.f|membership|" + newManager
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/SetSingleValueProfileProperty",
        type: "POST",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)

            var successHtml = '<div class="ms-MessageBar ms-MessageBar--success"><div class="ms-MessageBar-content"><div class="ms-MessageBar-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--checkboxCheck ms-Icon--circle"></i>'+
                                '</div><div class="ms-MessageBar-text">El Responsable se ha modificado con Exito!'+
                                '</div></div></div>';
            $("#userManager").html(successHtml);
            document.getElementsByClassName("ms-u-slideUpOut10").show();

        },
        error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqxr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin center > sharepoint > user profiles. ( need sharepoint admin rights)

Click on Manage user properties

Find & Edit the manager property.

Change the setting as below. Wait for couple of mins.

[image]

Run your code again, it should work.

Comment: Thanks Gautam, but I dont like user can change ther own "Manager" property.

Comment: It's an either or unfortunately, you either allow this so it can be edited or it gets updated via Azure AD Connect synchronization only.